# Detection Algorithm in 2D Images

Tags: image-processing

Suppose there is a two-deimensional image which consists of pixels. In every pixel, there are 0 to n apples with different colors， which can be digitalized(e.g.[0,10000]).

So we can plot a histogram for the color distribution of apples in every pixel. Some color may be more significant in this histogram. Let's call them color bumps.

The image below is for one pixel. 
[image: histogram]
How to detect areas (they also consist of pixels ) with a particular color bump? In this kind of areas, apples in color channel, say [0.2,0.5] are more significant than apples in other channels.

The shape of an area is irregular generally. We can set color channel we are interested in and the lower limit of significane.

My idea is:

We need to find a pixel as a seed, let it grow, and set criteria to find the boundary where a growth stops.

Or we find pixels one by one, then connect pixels to from a continuous area.

Which kind of algorithm is good at this? You have ever met this kind of example in practise?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are displaying in the image? It sounds like it's the "average" (combined) color of all points in a part of some other image  (and you are calling that part a "grid") ?

Comment: @Peter it is clearer now?

Comment: What do you mean when you say: _"In everypixel, there are 0 to n points"_?

Comment: By color band do you mean red, blue and green? or also other colors?

Comment: You need to add the scale that you are using, and how you are asigning the colors to that image and what color space are you using.  When You said that the picture posted has colors from 1 to 2, that´s not true since you said you were working with 3 channels. If you are using 3 channels you need a vector of 3 elements to say the color of a pixel.

Comment: @Alexander   It is clearer, now?

Comment: Well, that helps a little bit more,  but what is your criteria to determine the richness of a color? E.g. is rich in red if the value is 0, or is rich in red if the value is 1.2

Comment: As I can see you are not using the rgb color space, what are you using?

Comment: @Alexander  The color displayed now is meaningless in fact.  I should use grey.

Comment: Well, I guess that will be better explain your question in that context, because I cannot understand yet

Comment: There's a technique called flood-fill, you select a pixel and the algorithm find all the neighbors that share the same gray level, the algorithm iterates until all the connected pixels with the same gray level are detected.

Comment: @Alexander  I add more to explain the data space. The grey level has nothing to do with the detection in fact.

Comment: @Alexander  If there are bumps in an area, the significance levels of the bumps are not necessarily the same in different pixels.

Comment: Definitely I give up :(, I couldn't understand, I'm sorry

Comment: @Alexander I have re-written the post. I believe you can understand it now.

Comment: Please read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and Correct the Question

Comment: Wow, thats much better!

Answer (score 2):

Well, what I get from your question is that what you want to do is segmentation. First you need to consider how many bumps you want to detect, because in every pixel exist a set of probabilities for every bump. I am going to try to explain it in an exaple.

Imagine that you are working with a MRI image like this one:

[image]

Suppose you want to classify the different tissues that appear in it, due to the tissues in MRI look to have a gray tone deppending on what kind of tissue are (gray matter, white matter, skull, skin, not-a-tissue, etc).

I am going to work with assuming that in the image exists 6 types of tissues (including the not-a-tissue region or black zone). [In terms of apples I am going to have a combination of apples in each pixel of 6 different colors and I am goig to find what color is predominant in each pixel]

To classify and labeling each tissue I am going to resort to GMMF ( Gaussian Marcov Fields). And this will be my results:

[image]

In the set of binarized imges, each pixel shows the principal bump in it. But in the upper set, the probability of each bump in the pixel is shown.

Finally this is the algorithm to perform the GMMF:

```
% A Gaussian Kernel that will be needed
%Kernel Gaussiano
kmu=   [0 0]'
ko=    [2 2]'
kSize= 15
vi= [1/ko(1) 0; 0 1/ko(2)].^2
kS=floor(kSize/2);
for i=-kS:1:kS
    for j=-kS:1:kS
       d=[i,j]'-kmu;
       g(1+i+kS,1+j+kS)=(1/((sqrt(2*pi))*(sqrt(det(vi)))))*exp(-0.5*d'*vi*d)
    end
end

% 1: Assum some initial conditions (umbrals, means, variances)

mu=[10 50 90 130 170 210] //My initial hypotesis of which color is each
                          //tissue
o= [ 5  5  5   5   5   5] //My initial hypotesis of how much varies each 
                          //tissue
E=[mu o] // My vector of results to stablish a stop criterion for the 
         // algorithm
e=sqrt(E*E') // My tolerance criterion (The squared root of the sum of each    
             //squared element of the vector sqrt(E1^2 + E2^2 + ... + En^2)

while e>0.5 % e<3
    Ei=E //To compare how much imporve my results

    t=0:255  // A vector for the possible gray tones in the image
    T=zeros(1,256) // A vector of zeros

    for h=1:length(mu) //length(mu) =6 in this case
        T=(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*o(h)))*exp(-(0.5*(t-mu(h)).^2)/(o(h)*o(h)))
    end

% 2: Computing some likely hoods
    for h=1:length(mu)
        l(:,:,h)=(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*o(h)))*exp(-(0.5*(I-mu(h)).^2)/(o(h)*o(h)))
    end

% 3: Normalizing
    L=zeros(size(I))
    for h=1:length(mu)
        L=L+l(:,:,h)
    end
    for h=1:length(mu)
        p(:,:,h)=l(:,:,h)./L
    end

% 4: Smoothing ussing gaussian kerbell

    for h=1:length(mu)
       ps(:,:,h)=conv2(p(:,:,h),g,'same')
    end


    B=max(ps,[],3)
    for h=1:length(mu)
        b(:,:,h)=ps(:,:,h)==B
    end

% 5: Expectations

    for h=1:length(mu)
        aP(h)= 1/sum(sum(b(:,:,h)))
        mu(h)=aP(h)*sum(sum(I.*b(:,:,h)))
        o(h)=sqrt(aP(h)*sum(sum(((I-mu(h)).^2).*b(:,:,h))))
    end
    E=[mu o]
    e=sqrt((E-Ei)*(E-Ei)')

end
```

The algorithm is written in matlab type, I add some comentaries in c style, I hope you can run it. I would like to explain it better, good luck.

Comment: could you please say more about "In the set of binarized imges, each pixel shows the principal bump in it. But in the upper set, the probability of each bump in the pixel is shown."? For example,  could you plese explain one upper figure and its corresponding lower figure?

Comment: Yep!, let's take the first pair of images which represent the region where there isn't any tissue. In the upper image you can see the probability of all the pixels that aren't a tissue, high probabilities are represented by white while low probabilities are darker. In the other image a process of binarization was applied in order to show all the pixels classified as no-tissue regions

Comment: so for me, I need to calculate a valur for every pixel, which corresponds the 1st image. Then in order to search for interesting areas, I need to run binarization to get the second image, right?  A second question is,  why the two images are very similar?

Comment: I have no idea of how handle your case. In the example that I posted I am assuming that a single pixel has a set of probabilities of being any of the six types of tissue. In this case I am assuming six types of tissue: 1. No tissue, 2. Cefalorraquideous liquid, 3. Gray matter,  4. White matter, 5. Skull and 6. Skin. Now, if we take a look of the probabilities of one pixel in the corner, we know in advance that  this pixel corresponds to the non-tissue region, so the probabilities for the six types of tissue may look similar to [0.95, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01] and the sum of all the probabi

Comment: probabilities shoul be one. Now if we look one of the pixels that belongs to the no-tissue region, but is near to the skin, the probabilities may look like [0.7, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.26] now, that pixel has a high probability of being a not a tissue, but the pixel also has a considerable probability of being skin. So we need to establish a criterion for this pixel to say if it is  or not a certain kind of tissue. This is the purpose of binarization. A white pixel in the second image shows that the pixel has been labeled as a pixel that belongs to the region in question.

Comment: Finally in my case I handle the binarization in this way, find the maximum probability of all the six clases of tissue, assign a white color to its corresponding class and a black color to  the other classes

Comment: In my case, we can give significance of the bump I am interested in.  The only thing left is to join pixels.  But different areas may have different significance. It is like Middle East is rich in oil. South America is also rich in oil. But the signifiances in the two areas are different.  Middle East is  more significant. What I am trying to do is finding 'Middle East' or 'South America'.

Comment: I though my case was easier.

Comment: Is just you make it look more complicated than it really is

Comment: If you are interested in one bump why don't isolate that bump and make a 2d image of it and normalize it in terms of the standard images, 255 gray tone for the max value and 0 gray tone for the min value. After that you can apply the above algorithm and choose the number of regions what you want to see

Comment: In other words, my answer is for 1 channel images, and it can be extended to n channels, and probably it won't be a good approach due to the time consumption. In the way that you explained your case your image has 10000/x, channels

Comment: let's me try the data first. It may takes me several weeks